# Code formatting break Jekyll YAML front matter directives in VS code

Tags: jekyll, visual-studio-code

Auto code formatting (action `editor.action.format`) breaks [Jekyll (aka Github Pages)](http://jekyllrb.com) pages [YAML front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).

*index.html* before auto formatting:

```
--- 
layout: default 
title: Awesome page
bodyClass: homepage 
permalink: /
---
(rest of the content)
```

*index.html* after autoformatting:

```
--- layout: default title: Awesome page bodyClass: homepage permalink: / ---
(rest of the content is formatted ok, regular html syntax)
```

How can I tune up the VS code formatting rules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To resolve this, you have two options:

1. Turned off formatting of HTML files in `settings.json` file:

   ```
   "html.format.enable": false
   ```

   This turns off formatting off for HTML files. Not ideal, but gets the job done. There's a GitHub [Issue for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24088), but it looks to have been closed.
2. Consider installing the [Liquid Languages Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilding.language-liquid) extension then adding this to your `settings.json`:

   ```
   "files.associations": {
       "*.html": "liquid"
   }
   ```

This has resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The [Jekyll Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ginfuru.vscode-jekyll-snippets) extension causes VS Code to understand front matter on most file types.

The extension doesn't know about SCSS, however. A big-hammer workaround is to turn off SCSS validation in `settings.json`:

```js
"scss.validate": false
```

Comment: Highlighting doesnt work for me with js files - by default it's set up for html, md and jekyll file types.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Make sure you have this setting set as false:
`"editor.formatOnSave": false`

Comment: thanks @yviedev, though I know that. This does not solve the question, as I want auto code formatting for my other files.