# What's the correct way to add front matter data in 11ty?

Tags: eleventy

I am following [the documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-frontmatter/) to add frontmatter data to an html-turned into .njk file and when I save the file, the metadata gets parsed and it gets rearranged in this format :

```
-- -title : My page title
layout : 'base.njk'
-- -
```

Do I need to install any VS extension so that the metadata functions correctly on my files ?

Comment: I seem to have resolved the issue by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015963/code-formatting-break-jekyll-yaml-front-matter-directives-in-vs-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code formatting break Jekyll YAML front matter directives in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015963/code-formatting-break-jekyll-yaml-front-matter-directives-in-vs-code)